# Passing arguments to daemon from other processes

Tags: c++, c, signals, daemon, inter-process-communicat

I recently wrote a daemon in c++ that backs up certain folders by periodically copying a directory (and its contents) on my computer to an external flash drive. So far I can only back up one directory with a specific fixed path that I set in my source code. I would like to be able to pass an argument from another process to the daemon, while it is running, to change the path of the directory I want to backup. I have done research on signals like kill(), but I do not think that they are the correct kind of inter-process communication for my specific application.

Any help or direction as to how I should accomplish this task is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for and read about *named pipes*, or *local sockets*.

Comment: C is **not** C++ is **not** C!

Comment: @Olaf in the case of my question the two languages should have similar if not identical functions for inter-process communication. So no, you're right this is not C, but there is a strong relation and I believe it is appropriate to add the C tag so that people with knowledge in C can provide input on this question.

Comment: Any reasonable answer should use the language as it is meant to. For C++ this would mean non-C compatible/deprecated features like casting `void *` for malloc or (better) using `new`. You certainly would not add COBOL or Python tags either!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pipes` or shared memory see [poping 2 processes](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/116373/)